# iOS 8 - Web radio application with player on locked screen

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm trying to create a web radio application. For now, I'm able to play music from a streaming web radio, even when my application is on background (thanks to Background modes and the AVAudioSession singleton) I would like to know if I would be able, with the AVAudioPlayer class I'm using, to use the device music player to stream my web radio on the device locked screen and control it [(see the screenshot I provided as an example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9ffQ.png) .

Thanks for reading me,

Maël

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an issue to my problem. All I had to do is to use the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/index.html) and to set informations like the song title. The audio controls show themselves automatically when you play sound thanks to the AVAudioSession singleton.